# How to save short unicode HTML file as a table field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, unicode, javafx-2

I'm using hibernate 4 with JPA 2 and I'll use it with Derby, MySQL or SQL Server!(Anyway shouldn't be important)

I want to save a small (<10kb) html file in a table field. The html should be in Unicode. But I wonder how to define the data type in the entity class and how to force it to be written and read as Unicode(utf8). Either in Java or in the annotations and when I will display it in the browser component of JavaFX2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of table field that should be database agnostic:

```java
@Basic(fetch = LAZY) //lazy loading is optional
@Lob
@Column(name = "HTML", columnDefinition = "text", length = 10240)
private String html;
```

As for UTF-8 encoding you may try with Hibernate based connection properties

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="see below" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="utf8" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
```

or eventually with JDBC URL, i.e.

```
<property name="connection.url" 
          value="jdbc:DatabaseProvider://host:port/DatabaseName?URLAttributes"/>
```

where URL attributes are (apart from the others):

- characterEncoding=utf8
- connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
- useUnicode=true

NOTE: it may be required to use `UTF-8` instead of `utf8` (or vice versa)
NOTE: value of `hibernate.dialect` depends on [the underlying database](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)